# android fragments with lists and autocompletetextview

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I am having issue getting android auto complete text view to show filtered list items as well as the lists if used instead of auto complete text view do not show at all.

Below are snippet showing my code to use fragments for two cases:

```
private boolean isAuto = false;

private void switchView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = null;
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("from", fromList);
        b.putSerializable("to", toList);

        if(isAuto){
            if(autoCompleteFragment == null) {
                autoCompleteFragment = new AutoCompleteFragment();
            }
            f = autoCompleteFragment;
        } else {
            if(listClassicFragment == null) {
                listClassicFragment = new ListClassicFragment();
            }
            f = listClassicFragment;
        }
        f.setArguments(b);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, f);
        ft.commit();

    }
```

Here is custom adapter for both views:

```
public static class EntryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String>> {
        List<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String>> data;
        public EntryArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String>> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

            data = objects;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView t = new TextView(getContext());
            t.setText(data.get(position).getValue());
            t.setTag(data.get(position).getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "" + t.getText() + ":" + t.getTag());
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Here is fragment activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/from_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" 

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/to_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/to_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/value_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" 

                >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="20" 
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/result" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/submit_label" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

list view fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/from_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/to_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

list fragment the lists are not showing up.  I see that list fragment class onCreateView is getting called.  I suspect the custom adapter needs modification.

list fragment uses adapter as and lists do not show up:

```
fromAdapter = new EntryArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from);
            toAdapter = new EntryArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, to);
```

auto complete view uses it as and its edit text fields show up but filtering is not working:

```
 fromList.setAdapter(new EntryArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, from));
        toList.setAdapter(new EntryArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, to));
```

Please guide.

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 0):

The lists would not appear well due to its settings for width and height.  I changed the list layout as below and it shows up fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/from_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/to_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

For autoviewcomplete to work well I changed customer adapter as below:
public static class FilteredEntryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter> {
        List> data, filteredData;
        public FilteredEntryArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

```
        data = objects;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView t = new TextView(getContext());
        t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t.setText(filteredData.get(position).getValue());
        t.setTag(filteredData.get(position).getKey());
        Log.d(TAG, t.getText().toString());
        return t;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "entryadapter:" + filteredData.size());

        return filteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemId called for " + arg0);

        return filteredData.get(arg0).getKey().hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * return CurrencyEntry whose toString is overridden to return only Value
     */
    @Override
    public SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String> s = filteredData.get(position);
        return new CurrencyEntry(s);
    }




    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
       return new Filter()
       {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
                if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
                {
                    results.values = data;
                    results.count = data.size();
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String>> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String>>();

                    for(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String> d : data)
                    {
                        //In this loop, you'll filter through originalData and compare each item to charSequence.
                        //If you find a match, add it to your new ArrayList
                        //I'm not sure how you're going to do comparison, so you'll need to fill out this conditional
                        if(d.getValue().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        {
                            filterResultsData.add(d);
                        }
                    }            

                    results.values = filterResultsData;
                    results.count = filterResultsData.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
            {

                // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
                if (filterResults.count == 0)
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                else {
                    filteredData = (ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,String>>)filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

For items to show up well in autocompletetext view I changed list entry as:

public static class CurrencyEntry extends SimpleImmutableEntry {

```
    public CurrencyEntry(Entry<? extends String, ? extends String> arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getValue();
    }
}
```

Regards,

Miten.